# Kurento webrtc video doesn't play from remote server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento

I've installed kurento media server locally using docker, and created a Node.js app to communicate with it.

I have two types of clients, presenter clients & viewer clients.
Everything works on the **local** environment using self signed SSL certificate, I can also connect from other devices on local network.

Now I want to make it work from **AWS**, I created CloudFormation stack using template file, from [kurento installation guide](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html), and deployed my Node.js server to a different EC2 instance.

The problem is that the video doesn't play on viewer clients. 
The communication with Node.js app works the same as in local & [sdpAnswer](https://gist.github.com/AmitBu/b2640e2210d29860f2e8530628efdff7) arrives.

My first guess was that it's a certificate error, so I linked my domain to CloudFlare, and used its SSL service.
But the video still doesn't play.

Also, I checked The TURN server, that the template created, it seems to be working:
[image: Trickle ICE check]

All ports are currently open on both EC2 instances.

What am I missing here? And how could I troubleshoot it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, in my case I forgot to call:

```
webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(candidate);
```

In my client side app, when candidates arrived from server.

Comment: In the client app, when I received the candidate data as parameter from the socket event (data.candidate), and added it to the webrtc peer object: `webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(candidate);`